# webkit extension load local file

Tags: vala

How to load a local file (vala):

```
web_extension.page_created.connect((extension, web_page)=> {
var dom = web_page.get_dom_document();

WebKit.DOM.Element img = dom.create_element("img");
img.set_attribute("src", "file:///home/USER/image.jpg");
dom.body.insert_before(img, null);
...
}
```

Local path does not work, only http(s).

Answer (score 0):

- If the web page is served over HTTP(S), I'd expect it cannot access `file://` resources for security reasons.
- If the web page is loaded from a `file://` resource, it may be necessary to play with 
  [allow-file-access-from-file-urls](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitSettings.html#WebKitSettings--allow-file-access-from-file-urls) and [allow-universal-access-from-file-urls](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitSettings.html#WebKitSettings--allow-universal-access-from-file-urls) WebKit.Settings properties.

[Example](https://github.com/tiliado/nuvolaplayer/blob/master/src/nuvolakit-runner/formatsupport/FormatSupportDialog.vala#L131):

```
var web_view = new WebKit.WebView();
#if HAVE_WEBKIT_2_10
web_view.get_settings().allow_file_access_from_file_urls = true;
#endif
#if HAVE_WEBKIT_2_14
web_view.get_settings().allow_universal_access_from_file_urls = true;
#endif
```

You (or your build system) should define the `HAVE_WEBKIT_2_10` and `HAVE_WEBKIT_2_14` Valac pre-processor flags according to the version of WebKitGTK+ on your system.